# Can't access filed from xaml template through FieldInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reflection

I have xaml template for my MainWindow class:

```
...    
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" Click="button1_Click"  />
<Label x:Name="superLabel" Content="Super content!" />
...
```

I wanna access **superLabel** field through relfections, after button click, like this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Type t = typeof(MainWindow);
  FieldInfo test1 = t.GetField("superLabel"); //  test1 == null
  FieldInfo test2 = t.GetRuntimeField("superLabel"); // test2 == null
  ...
}
```

but I am getting **null** in every test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label is not `public` - you should add `BindingFlags` as second argument:

```
FieldInfo test1 = t.GetField("superLabel", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
```